# How to find object in object array in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have an object array like this:

```
result = [{
        email: 'jaiswal.shubham84@gmail.com',
        profile: './image/jaiswal.shubham84@gmail.com/6.jpg'
    },
    {
        email: 'sj1303058@gmail.com',
        profile: './image/sj1303058@gmail.com/5.jpg'
    }
]
```

How can I find the right object in `result` based on `email`?

Comment: What you exactly want give some more details

Comment: i have an array of object and structure of each object is like {email:'somevalue' , profile:'someothervalue'}, i simple want to find the object from the array using email as a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Gabriel Bleu answered it pretty well. I would just add this: if you want all the object matching your condition, use filter instead for find:

```js
result = [{
        email: 'jaiswal.shubham84@gmail.com',
        profile: './image/jaiswal.shubham84@gmail.com/6.jpg'
    },
    {
        email: 'sj1303058@gmail.com',
        profile: './image/sj1303058@gmail.com/5.jpg'
    },{
        email: 'jaiswal.shubham84@gmail.com',
        profile: 'heyehye'
    },
    {
        email: 'hahahahaha@gmail.com',
        profile: 'hahahaha'
    }
]

//every matching email. Returns an array of all matching (even if only one)
const filtered = result.filter(r => r.email === 'jaiswal.shubham84@gmail.com')
//only one. Will be the first one found so returns an object
const found = result.find(r => r.email === 'jaiswal.shubham84@gmail.com')

console.log("filtered : " + JSON.stringify(filtered))
console.log("found : " + JSON.stringify(found))
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const result = [
  {
    email: 'jaiswal.shubham84@gmail.com',
    profile: './image/jaiswal.shubham84@gmail.com/6.jpg'
  },
  {
    email: 'sj1303058@gmail.com',
    profile: './image/sj1303058@gmail.com/5.jpg'
  }
];

const jaiswal = result.find(it => it.email === 'jaiswal.shubham84@gmail.com');
console.log(jaiswal);
```

Answer (score 0):

npm the lodash if not installed previously

var lodash=require("lodash");

```
function getobject(array,keyvalue)
{

  var obj = lodash.filter(array, { 'email': keyvalue } );

  return picked[0].profile;
}
```